# CS50 caesar.c - ciphertext printing out of ASCII code range

Tags: c, cs50

I'm going through CS50 (2021x version) of Caesar problem, and ran into problem. My program is printing outside of ASCII range (thanks to curiouskiwi over at discord for this hint). The error message says ":( encrypts "barfoo" as "yxocll" using 23 as key, output not valid ASCII text". Another one I'm having trouble is "world, say hello!", for same reason (Not valid ASCII text). Other ones are encrypting fine.

I've stepped through the debugger and found that 'letter' variable is sometimes becoming a negative integer like -119'/211', but can't figure out why that may be so. I expected to see positive value associated with an alphabet in ASCII. When this happens the letters will stop printing on the console.

If I type ./caesar 23 | cat -A and then give barfoo as plaintext, the cyphertext will come out as yxM-^IcM-^FM-^F$.

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // only 1 arugment, and positive argument only
    if (argc == 2 && argv[1] > 0)
    {
        // check if each char of argument is digit
        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
        {
            if (isdigit(argv[1][i]))
            {
                // do nothing
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }

        // change the key to how much letters should move over
        int input = atoi(argv[1]);
        int key = input % 26;
        char letter;

        // get the input
        string text = get_string("plaintext: ");
        printf("ciphertext: ");

        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
        {
            if (isalpha(text[i])) // if it is an alphabet
            {
                if (islower(text[i])) // if it is lowercase
                {
                    letter = text[i] + key; // add key to text[i]
                    if (letter > 122)
                    {
                        // loop around the alphabet
                        letter -= 26;
                    }
                    printf("%c", letter);
                }
                else // if it is uppercase
                {
                    letter = text[i] + key; // add key to text[i]
                    if (letter > 90)
                    {
                        // loop around the alphabet
                        letter -= 26;
                    }
                    printf("%c", letter);
                }
            }
            else // if it is not an alphabet
            {
                printf("%c", text[i]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `argv[1] > 0` is not the right way to check for NULL or length of string, just checking value of `argc`  should be enough

Comment: BTW you don't need to check `isalpha()` before `islower()` or `isupper()`. b) don't hard code magic numbers, use `'Z'` instead of `90`.

Comment: Sorry, I think I wrote unclear code. On that line I'm trying to check if the user has entered non-negative number. Would there be a better way to write it?

Comment: 3) `letter = text[i] + key;` should be `if(isupper(text[i])) {letter = (text[i] - 'A' + key) % 26 + 'A';}` etc because the key might be many multiples of 26.

Comment: You need to do the `atoi` first, then verify that `input` is a non-negative number.

Comment: Use `int letter` instead of `char letter` because `'z' + 23` overflows the range of `char` and is negative.  Generally, a beginners mistake is to think "a character is a `char`" but `'A'` is an `int` and most of the character-oriented library functions use `int` not `char` as the type of a single character.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand what's been happening now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `int letter` instead of `char letter`.

This is because

```
letter = text[i] + key;
```

will overflow signed `char` for, say, `'z' + 23`.